# Why don't we use Yahuah?

Tags: names-of-god, tetragrammaton

Why don't we use God's actual name, Yahuah? I came across this link: http://promotethetruth.com/id1.html
and some of the items brought up made sense (especially the very last two paragraphs).

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE!  A bit of food for thought: (a) Given all the accents in the world, if the correct pronunciation of God's name is more important than knowing Him, a lot of us are putting a lot of effort into being charitable for nothing.  (b) If [the Jews are still debating how to pronounce His name](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=pronunciation+of+god%27s+name), then I don't trust any Christian website that claims definitive proof without claiming prophetship.  It's not as indisputable as some want to believe, so I'm glad He's in the forgiving business.

Comment: @A.Macfarland Who is "we"?

Comment: Pastors, people in general, the bible.

Comment: I guess my question would be, am I deceived or sinning if I am not praying/saying "Yahuah"? Example: John 5:43 where it says "in my Father's name". Well wouldn't His name be Yahuah? I am just trying to understand better.

Comment: Hi A. We deliberately don't answer "is this a sin" questions here, because different Christian groups have different opinions on these things.  You could ask about some particular group, as to whether they consider not using God's name a sin. Please edit the question if you want to change what you ask.

Comment: You should also be aware that lots of people do use God's name, YAHWEH or YHWH (Yahuah is just a different way of spelling the same word). You can read more about the name, which is sometimes referred to as the [Tetragrammaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragrammaton). Wikipedia will give you some information, but a good bible dictionary will give you more and better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: - because we cannot be sure about correct pronunciation.

Longer answer:

Biblical hebrew language is quite peculiar, i.e. most vovels are not written which makes pronounciation ambiguous:

> "The letters YHWH are consonantal semi-vowels. In unpointed Biblical Hebrew, most vowels are not written and the rest are written only ambiguously, as certain consonants can double as vowel markers (similar to the Latin use of V to indicate both U and V). These are referred to as matres lectionis ("mothers of reading"). Therefore, it is, in general, difficult to deduce how a word is pronounced only from its spelling, and the tetragrammaton is a particular example: two of its letters can serve as vowels, and two are vocalic place-holders, which are not pronounced. Thus the first-century Jewish historian and philosopher Josephus said that the sacred name of God consists of "four vowels"."
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragrammaton#Pronunciation)

As You can see even from comments, there is endless dispute among scholars, how JHWH should be pronounciated.

On the other hand, unlike in modern era, in Bible names had real, important meanings, e.g. :

> "20 And Adam called his wife's name Eve; because she was the mother of all living."

(KJV Gen. 3.20)

Now let's get to YHWH:

What does it mean ?

> "There are several views of what YHWH means and where the term originated. The most commonly accepted is that the term comes from "Y" (Hebrew yodh י) meaning "he," and the Proto-Semitic root "HWY," (> Hebrew: he waw he היה ) which means either "to be" or "to create" depending on context, mode and inflection, making YHWH "He who is" or alternately "He who creates.""
>   [Rational wiki](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/YHWH)
>
> "Epiphanius (died 404), who was born in Palestine and spent a considerable part of his life there, gives Ἰά (Ia) and Ἰάβε (pronounced at that time /ja'vε/) and explains Ἰάβε as meaning He who was and is and always exists."
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragrammaton#Patristic_writings)

Now let's check what God himself says about His name:

> "13 And Moses said unto God, Behold, when I come unto the children of Israel, and shall say unto them, The God of your fathers hath sent me unto you; and they shall say to me, What is his name? what shall I say unto them?
>
> 14 And God said unto Moses, I AM THAT I AM: and he said, Thus shalt thou say unto the children of Israel, I AM hath sent me unto you.
>
> 15 And God said moreover unto Moses, Thus shalt thou say unto the children of Israel, The LORD God of your fathers, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob, hath sent me unto you: this is my name for ever, and this is my memorial unto all generations."

(KJV Exodus 3.13-15)

( Note that in original text there is YHWH instead of "LORD", which is God's name - [Interlinear bible](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/exodus/3.htm))

So if You say : YHWH (just like that) or: "God of Abraham, the God of Isaac..."
or : "The God that always been, is and always will be"
or even :

> "8 ... Alpha and Omega, the beginning and the ending, saith the Lord, which is, and which was, and which is to come, the Almighty."

(KJV Revelation 1.8)

You cannot go wrong regardless of translation, Your native language, or other factors, since according to Christianity, only ONE entity in the universe fulfills this description. All other "gods" were created or had their beginning.

As a side note i must say, that it is very unlikely, that YHWH would not take care of giving us specific instructions on pronounciation if it was THAT important.

kind regards

Comment: This is a useful answer. It would be more complete if you added information about the history of deliberately avoiding pronouncing the name. The quote from KJV has an example, where LORD is a substitute for YHVH in the original Hebrew.

Comment: @disciple: I am aware of this problem but it would be rather answer for another question :)